# Python: List shift

Tags: python

Given a

```
list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

How can I get a 2D List like:

```
2dList = [[0,1,2,3],[2,3,4,5],[4,5,6,7],[6,7,8,9],[8,9,10]]
```

(each 1st dimension of "2dList" has 4 values, there is a "shift" of 2 values from "list". When there isn't 4 values to fulfill the 1st dimension, it just store the last values from "list"]

?

thanks!

Comment: Why does it end with `[8, 9, 10]` and not `[6, 7, 8, 9]` or `[10]`?

Comment: a/list is a terrible name for a list b/ 2dList is not a valid name for a variable

Comment: it's not a "formal" code... just a piece of "pseudo".. it's not right to use "list" as a name variable, I know that...

Comment: @Veedrac it is not a duplicate because the chunks here are overlapping

Comment: @SaulloCastro So is the linked question. I did notice there was another supposed duplicate that does not overlap, but my linked one does.

Comment: And before someone says "but the shift value is **2**", that just means you take every other element from the iterator. It's the same question.

Comment: @Veedrac, you are right...I checked the other one with three closing votes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

move_amount = 2
slice_size = 4
print [my_list[i:i + slice_size] for i in range(
  0, len(my_list) - move_amount, move_amount)]
```

Comment: this outputs an extra `[10]` at the end. it can be debated as to whether it should be there or not, as it can be considered a valid piece of the output. To remove it, use `range(0, len(l) - move_amount, move_amount)`

Comment: oops, fixed.  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

IF you are willing to use `numpy` you can change the array strides in order to achieve what you want:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 11]) # added 11 to avoid a memory mess
as_strided(a, shape=(5,4), strides=(a.strides[0]*2, a.strides[0]))
#array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#       [ 2,  3,  4,  5],
#       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
#       [ 6,  7,  8,  9],
#       [ 8,  9, 10,  11]])
```

and in memory this is actually what it is in array `a`, which can be useful for some purposes...

Comment: ok, but let's imagine that I don't have a multiple of 4 elements, therefore I don't have "11" as last result...

Comment: should add `import numpy as np` to the top

Comment: @kairos, in that case this solution may be inadequate, or you can just add a dummy value at the end to ensure this requirement...